# ExtJS 4.2.1 XTemplate and subtemplates (statics)

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, static, extjs4.2

I got a custom `Ext.Component` with a view `XTemplates`. I do need some of theese Templates outside of the view in my controller too.

Is it possible to refer to static members in functions of a `XTemplate`. Or is there another much better way???

something like this:

```
Ext.define('app.view.ApplicationHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    name: 'app-header',
    xtype: 'app-header',

    height: 67,
    margin: 0,

    statics: {
        mainIconTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate'),

        navigationItemsTpl: new Ext.XTemplate( 'anotherTemplate'),

        userInfoTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('userTemplate')
    },

    html: new Ext.XTemplate('... {[ this.renderMainIcons() ]} {[ this.renderUserInfo() ]} ...',
            '... {[ this.renderNavigationBarItems() ]} ...',
            {
                me: this,
                renderMainIcons: function () {
                    return view.static.mainIconTpl.apply(MR.Sitemap.Items);
                },
                renderUserInfo: function () {
                    return view.static.userInfoTpl.apply();
                },
                renderNavigationBarItems: function () {
                    return view.static.navigationItemsTpl.apply();
                }
            }).apply()   
});
```

i also dont know how i could apply subtemplates which are members of the view. I declared them global right know which i really dont like to do.

please!

Comment: I don't see the problem with your proposed solution... Except maybe you should use `app.view.ApplicationHeader.mainIconTpl`, instead of `view.mainIconTpl` which is probably not defined. What kind of failure are you getting?

Comment: the problem is that i dont get the context of my view in this XTemplate functions... :/

Comment: i dont know how to get the static templates in my XTemplate if they're in the same view.. i cannot go with this.self... because this is already the XTemplate

Comment: `app` is not defined too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because the `apply` method of the main template is called **before** the class definition (i.e. the `define` method) is even called.

You can create your static template that uses the other static members of the class in the post-create function (see the last param of the [`define` method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-define)).

Then in order for the template to be available, I would override the `initComponent` method and set the `html` property there.

```
Ext.define('app.view.ApplicationHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    name: 'app-header',
    xtype: 'app-header',

    height: 67,
    margin: 0,

    statics: {
        mainIconTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate'),
        navigationItemsTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('anotherTemplate'),
        userInfoTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('userTemplate')
    },

    initComponent: function() {

        // Here, your statics are available, and you're in the scope of your
        // class *instance*
        this.html = this.self.viewTemplate.apply();

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

}, function() {

    // In the post create function, this is the class constructor
    // (i.e. app.view.ApplicationHeader)
    var cls = this;

    // In fact, you could also create your sub templates here if you prefer
    // e.g.
    // cls.useInfoTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('userTemplate')

    // So, viewTemplate will be a static property of the class
    cls.viewTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate('... {[ this.renderMainIcons() ]} {[ this.renderUserInfo() ]} ...',
        '... {[ this.renderNavigationBarItems() ]} ...', {
        renderMainIcons: function() {
            return cls.mainIconTpl.apply();
        },
        renderUserInfo: function() {
            return cls.userInfoTpl.apply();
        },
        renderNavigationBarItems: function() {
            return cls.navigationItemsTpl.apply();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the link, you should be able to put this directly in your XTemplate.  No need for statics

```
{[ MyApp.tpls.someOtherTpl.apply(values) ]}
```

[Multiple templates in Nested List](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?144725)

You could also try putting all of these XTemplates in initComponent instead since you're not injecting any values for XTemplate after initial component render.  The apply() will just return you an HTML fragment which should be able to be appended anywhere within the XTemplate.

If you're trying to put logical or conditional tpl operators i.e. <tpl for="parent.someVar">...</tpl> in any of the sub XTemplates, then that's another problem so it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

```
Ext.define('app.view.ApplicationHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    name: 'app-header',
    xtype: 'app-header',

    height: 67,
    margin: 0,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
        me.mainIconTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate'),
        me.navigationItemsTpl = new Ext.XTemplate( 'anotherTemplate'),
        me.userInfoTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('userTemplate');

        me.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '...', me.mainIconTpl.apply(MR.Sitemap.Items), 
            '...', me.navigationItemsTpl.apply(someValues), 
            '...', me.userinfoTpl.apply(someValues), 
            '...'
        );

        Ext.apply(me, {
             html: me.tpl
        });

        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: My idea for the statcs was because i need to rerender just one subtemplate in the controller of the component. is there a better solution for this? i do have conditional tpl operators but i dont think that they're the probleme..